# Lee metric, Gilbert-Varshamov and Hamming bounds for larger relative distance ranges

Tags: coding-theory

[Gardy and Sole](ftp://ftp.cs.brown.edu/pub/techreports/91/cs91-29.pdf) provide a Gilbert-Varshamov lower bound and a Hamming upper bound for the Lee metric when the distance between codewords is smaller than the length of the code (captured by $r = \delta n$ where $0 \le \delta \le 0.37$ in the paper).

Is there a reference which provides the corresponding lower/upper bound for ranges above this? At least is there a lower bound (preferably as powerful as the Gilbert-Varshamov bound) and a upper bound(preferably tighter than the Hamming bound) for the case $\frac{2 \delta n + 1}{n} = \frac{n + 1}{n}$, that is $\delta = \frac{1}{2}$?

*This is a smaller version of the cross-posting from [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70524/lee-metric-constructive-and-asymptotic-bounds).*

Comment: Closed for _simultaneous_ [cross-posting on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/70524/lee-metric-constructive-and-asymptotic-bounds). If you don't get an answer on MO after a few days, flag the post and we will reopen it.

Comment: @Kaveh ok Thankyou